# Can't display view from controller / route in hmvc laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, module, hmvc

i follow this [link](http://creolab.hr/2013/05/modules-in-laravel-4/)
to create project hmvc in laravel
my structure file like this

```
+ [app]
  + [Another Directory]
  + [modules]
    + [content]
    + [shop]
      + [controllers]
        - ShopController.php
      + [view]
        - home.blade.php
      - route.php
      - ServiceProvider.php
    - ServiceProvider.php 
+ [Another Directory]
```

this is my shopController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Modules\Shop\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use View;

class ShopController extends BaseController {

    public function showWelcome() {
        return View::make('shop::home');
    }

}
```

and this is my route in shop module

```
<?php

Route::get('/shop', 'App\\Modules\\Shop\\Controllers\\ShopController@showWelcome');
```

i try to test return simple hello string from route in shop module and it's working

```
<?php 
Route::get('admin/shop', function() {
   return '<h1>Hello</h1>';
});
```

but where i'm missing
so can't display view from route or controller in hmvc

---

**@update Jan.J**

route in shop module

```
//this is working
Route::get('admin/shop', function() {
  return '<h1>hello</h1>';
});

//this is working, result laravel default page hello in view mvc
// but i can't dispay view in shop module
Route::get('admin/shop', function() {
  return View::make('hello');
});

//i try your script something like this, and it's not working
//correct me if i'm wrong
 Route::get('/shop', 'new App\Modules\Shop\Controllers\ShopController(app('request'));');
```

---

**@update**

i try to update my shop route to call view in shop module like this

```
<?php 
Route::get('test/', function() {
    return View::make(‘shop::home’);
});
```

and it's give result 
`Class '‘shop' not found`

any idea?

Comment: Maybe it's only typo here in question, but your directory is named [Module], but you refer to it like Modules. If your composer autoloading points to inexistent directory that would lead to those errors.

Comment: @Jan.J yeah it's typo, my directory name is modules....but i refer it with Capital M, same with example in creolab...is that ok?

Comment: Yes, classmap autoloading will take care of this. You could try to instantiate your controller somewhere else and see if class is being properly loaded. And before that run `composer autoload`.

Comment: @Jan.J hm how about if i try to call view in module shop by route (route shop) first without controller...do you have idea how to do it..maybe from that i get fairy idea where i'm missing

Comment: This should work: `new App\Modules\Shop\Controllers\ShopController(app('request'));`

Comment: @Jan.J where i place that code? in route shop?

Comment: In some already working route.

Comment: @Jan.J i already try it..please see my update post

Answer (score 2):

Check controller class like that:

```
Route::get('/shop', function () {
    $controller = new App\Modules\Shop\Controllers\ShopController(app('request'));
    var_dump($controller);
});
```

Is it working? Do you see class dump? OR if not what error is displayed.

Comment: no it's give error `Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script`

Comment: What file does this error come from? You should check it.

Comment: i already check it..and it's from shopController php
i already post my shopController.php in my post and don't know where i'm missing